# FastAPI multiple routes bound to same function. How to know which one was requested

Tags: python, fastapi

Let's say I have 2 routes pointing to the same function

```
from fastapi import FastApi

app = FastApi()

@app.get('/api/')
@app.get('/api/test')
def main_route():
    ...
```

Both routes will call `main_route` function, but I want to know which route was used. Query parameters shouldn't be used in there. I was thinking of using `request` object but I want to know if there is a simpler solution for that.

Comment: Cant get much simpler than `request.url.path == "/api/test"`

Comment: If you need to know which one was called, make them separate endpoints; move the common functionality into one or more helper functions instead.

Answer (score 21):

Definitely use the `Request` object here. You can run the below code as-is.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/api')
@app.get('/api/test')
def main_route(request: Request):
    return {"Called from": request.url.path}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: If  a route includes path parameters, e.g., `/api/test/{num}`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239186/17865804) on how to get the raw path (in the format of `/api/test/{num}`) that would better let you differentiate between the various routes bound to that function.