# How to get route's name using FastAPI/Starlette?

Tags: python, fastapi, middleware, starlette

How can I get the `name` of a route/endpoint using FastAPI/Starlette? I have access to the `Request` object and I need this information in one of my middlewares. For example, if I hit `services/1`, I should then be able to get the `abc` name. Is this possible in FastAPI?

```
@app.get("/services/{service}", name="abc")
async def list_services() -> dict:
    do something
```

Update 1: Output of `request.scope`

```
{'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.3'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('127.0.0.1', 8001), 'client': ('127.0.0.1', 56670), 'scheme': 'http', 'root_path': '', 'headers': [(b'user-agent', b'PostmanRuntime/7.29.2'), (b'accept', b'*/*'), (b'postman-token', b'f2da2d0f-e721-44c8-b14f-e19750ea8a68'), (b'host', b'localhost:8001'), (b'accept-encoding', b'gzip, deflate, br'), (b'connection', b'keep-alive')], 'method': 'GET', 'path': '/health', 'raw_path': b'/health', 'query_string': b'', 'app': <fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x1036d5790>}
```

Update 2:
Providing middleware code where `request.scope["route"]` is breaking.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,Request
    
app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def logging_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    print(request.scope['route'].name)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

@app.get('/', name='abc')
def get_name(request: Request):
    return request.scope['route'].name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

You can get the `name` value inside an endpoint as follows:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI,Request
    
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', name='abc')
def get_name(request: Request):
    return request.scope['route'].name
```

### Option 2

In a middleware, make sure to get the route's `name` after calling `call_next(request)`, otherwise you would be faced with `KeyError: 'route'`, as the `route` key/object would not yet exist in the `scope` dictionary. Example:

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    print(request.scope['route'].name)
    return response
```

### Option 3

Instead of a middleware, you could create a [custom `APIRoute` class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router), which would allow you to get the route's `name` **before** processing the `request` and getting the `response` (if that's a requirement for your app). You could add an endpoint that you would like to be handled by that `APIRoute` class using `@<name_of_router_instance>` instead of `@app` (e.g., `@router.get('/', name='abc')`). More than one endpoint could be added in the same way. Example:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Request, Response
from typing import Callable
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute

class CheckNameRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            print(request.scope['route'].name)
            response = await original_route_handler(request)
            return response

        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=CheckNameRoute)
    
@router.get('/', name='abc')
def get_name(request: Request):
    return request.scope['route'].name
 
app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: If one has access to the request object, why not use `request.url_for("route-name-here")`?