# Setting up a general FastAPI gateway ("Abstract" endpoint)

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to setup a completely general API route, that would take a request to any path, and forward it to another URL as is. Kind of like a middleware to another API. Or a gateway.

The catch: It has to work with any type of request. From JSON and HTML, to streaming, redirections, files, and forms.

This is what I currently have:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Path, UploadFile, HTTPException
import httpx
import os
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

app = FastAPI()

@app.api_route("/{relative_path:path}", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
async def apim_anonymous(request: Request, relative_path: str = Path(...)):
    headers_to_not_forward = ['host', 'connection', 'keep-alive', 'transfer-encoding', 'te', 'trailer', 'upgrade', 'proxy-*']
    forward_headers = {k: v for k, v in request.headers.items() if k.lower() not in headers_to_not_forward}

    content_type = request.headers.get('content-type')

    if content_type in ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data']:
        form_data = await request.form()
        body = {key: value for key, value in form_data.items()}
    else:
        body = await request.body()

    target_url = f"{os.environ['TARGET_URL']}/{relative_path}"
    query_string = str(request.url.query)
    target_url = f"{target_url}?{query_string}" if query_string else target_url

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        if content_type == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            response_coroutine = client.request(
                method=request.method,
                url=target_url,
                headers=forward_headers,
                data=body
            )
        elif content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
            files = {k: (v.filename, v.file, v.content_type) for k, v in body.items() if isinstance(v, UploadFile)}
            form = {k: v for k, v in body.items() if not isinstance(v, UploadFile)}

            response_coroutine = client.request(
                method=request.method,
                url=target_url,
                headers=forward_headers,
                data=form, 
                files=files
            )

        else:
            response_coroutine = client.request(
                method=request.method,
                url=target_url,
                headers=forward_headers,
                content=body
            )

        async with handle_api_response(response_coroutine) as response:
            return Response(content=response.content, status_code=response.status_code, headers=dict(response.headers))
        
@asynccontextmanager
async def handle_api_response(response_coroutine):
    try:
        response = await response_coroutine
        if "content-encoding" in response.headers:
            del response.headers["content-encoding"] # httpx unzips the response
        yield response

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
```

But it still doesn't work! It messes up something with the headers. I am not even sure.
Is this even the correct way to go about this? Do you have any suggestions as to how to continue?

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: This is the original answer I used, which didn't work. My solution was to rebuild the headers from scratch, forwarding only headers like `Authorization` , `Location` and `Content-Type`. Also there should be different build_request for content_type in 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data'.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76268510/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) helpful as well.