# How to modify the URL with a FastAPI request that is read-only in a middleware?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, middleware, api-gateway

I am developing a microservices system with FastAPI and implementing a gateway that routes requests to the corresponding microservices. My current problem is that I need to change the request URL within a middleware so that it can detect the other running containers, but the `request.url` property is read-only.

Here is the current middleware code:

```
@app.middleware('http')
async def route_to_microservice(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        path = request.url.path
        parts = path.split('/')
        microservice_name = get_microservice_name(parts)
        microservice_url = settings.MICROSERVICES.get(microservice_name)

        if microservice_url:
            # Build new URL in container perspective
            request.scope['path'] = '/'.join(parts[4:]) if len(parts) > 4 else ''
            response = await call_next(request)
            return response
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Microservice not found')
    except HTTPException as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={'error': e.detail}, status_code=e.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={'error': 'Internal Server Error'}, status_code=500)

def get_microservice_name(parts):
    if len(parts) > 3 and parts[1].lower() == 'api':
        return f'{parts[2]}-{parts[3]}'
    else:
        return None
```

My microservices setup looks like this:

```
MICROSERVICES: dict = {
    'users-v1': 'http://users-service-v1/',
    # Other microservices
}
```

How can I perform this URL modification within the middleware in FastAPI? Is there a way to achieve this without completely changing my design approach?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726959/how-to-re-route-requests-to-a-different-url-endpoint-in-fastapi/75729917#75729917) answer your question?

Comment: No, what I want is to pass the name in the docker service url, but I can't find a way to modify it.