# How to pass on request from one server to another in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

I have two different machines, each running same FastAPI() application, started with unicorn on port 3000. I am not sure what is the right approach to duplicate each route from the first server to the second one..

For example when the first server get

```
@router.post("/register_book")
async def register_book(
    request: RegisterBookRequest, db)
) -> Response:
....
```

What I look for is a way, that not only first server will proceed this request, but also same request will be sent from server A to server B.. something like

```
@router.post("/register_book")
async def register_book(
    request: RegisterBookRequest, db)
) -> Response:
....
// initiate the same synchronous request to <second server IP>:3000, wait for response
```

Any ideas? The best I guess something like

```
@router.post("/register_book")
@something.dupliate.request("<second_server_ip>:3000")
async def register_book(
    request: RegisterBookRequest, db)
) -> Response:
....
```

but I doubt it possible..thanks

Comment: Do you want to round robin between servers or are you looking for server 1 to pass on the request to server 2? If it was to do so, what would you do with the response from server 2?

Comment: server 1 to "duplicate" same request to server 2, server 1 will sync wait for response from server 2 and once it's completed, server 1 will return response to the client.. I sort of implement primary-secondary approach, where secondary is "hot"

Comment: will server 1 do anything but act as a proxy for server 2?

Comment: server 1 and server 2 both running identical FastAPI application..whatever route lands in Server 1 - it will need to process it locally and also duplicate request to Server 2 that will process it locally there..in example above method "register_book' need to be executed in both servers ..so it's not just a proxy

Comment: Please have a look at  [How to forward FastAPI requests to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

You can create [middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/).

```
import time

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def duplicate_request(request: Request, call_next):
    # Send request to server 2
    # You can send it in separate asyncio 
    # task and wait for results in the end of this
    # function (before return) 
    response = await call_next(request)
    # Wait for response from server 2
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I now see this one also related [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726959/how-to-re-route-requests-to-a-different-url-endpoint-in-fastapi/77533624#77533624] ..how to clone request into new request where I only modify URL to the end server?

Comment: I tried request._url = <new_url> but this doesn't work